# What is the reasoning behind "suggest a synonym" required reputation?

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

I can see the reasoning behind the need of 300 reputation before one can create new tags, but why do we need 2500 reputation just to *suggest* a tag synonym? Why is that action so much more important than the ability to create a whole new tag?

Answer (score 2):

I think I now know the answer. Creating a new tag is okay with some reputation, since if it turns out to be a not-so-good tag which nobody is really using, it simply gets automatically deleted by the system in six months. No big harm done.

> •new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period

Suggesting a synonym is (if the suggestion passes) more severe action, as it effectively removes the synonym-tag from the system. Yes, the old tag is still there, but all attempts to use it will turn up the approved synonym instead.

> Any tags that match active synonyms will be automatically and silently changed from their original as-entered form to the tag that the synonym points to.

That's why synonym creation is needing higher reputation than creating a new tag.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Also anyone relatively new to the site could suggest a tag, but creating synonyms might require more experience with the site to understand what you're getting into.

Comment: Also people could make a "lame" tag and make it a synonym for say Nikon or HDR!  See [tag-synonym-attracts-trolling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62323/tag-synonym-attracts-trolling?rq=1)